# What are RESTful web services?

Tags: web-services, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

What are RESTful web services? What would be an example of it?

What is the difference between the asmx web services and the WCF RESTful service?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check out Roy Fielding's (the creator of the REST architectural style) [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Fielding) page here and then move on to his PhD dissertation [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/) and finally for a quick example just take a look at the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/).

Answer (score 94):

REST is a client-server architecture which (among other things) leverages the full capacity of the HTTP protocol.

Some relevant points in REST:

- Each URL on the server represents a resource; either a *collection resource* or an *element resource*.

  - A **collection resource** would be available at a URL like `http://restful.ex/items/` which would be a *representation* of a list of items.
  - A **element resource** would be available at a URL like `http://restful.ex/items/2` which would be a *representation* of a single item, identified by `2`.
- Different HTTP methods are used for different CRUD operations:

  - a **GET** is a read operation
  - a **PUT** is a write/modify operation
  - a **POST** is a create/new operation
  - a **DELETE** is a... ok, that one is kind of self-explanatory.
- State (or rather, client context) is not stored on the server-side; all state is in the *representations* passed back and forth by the client's requests and the server's responses.

Comment: Thank you Richard for your clear expalanation about REST HTTP Protocol.

Answer (score 12):

It's basically web services that implement CRUD using the HTTP methods(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)

Answer (score 8):

RESTful webservices use HTTP methods explicitly by mapping the REST operations to HTTP methods:

- Create - POST
- Retrieve - GET
- Update - PUT
- Delete - DELETE

Here is a [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) to a good summary.

Comment: the proper "lingo" is **CRUD** (**C** reate, **R** ead, **U** pdate, **D** elete)

Answer (score 1):

Check description of [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer). Web services conforming to this principle are called RESTful.