# RESTful services to use GET and POST

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

With RESTful services I believe the user should be able to use GET or POST as they wish. The user should be able to put their parameters in the URL and/or Header of GET request and Header or body of POST request.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean that the user is the client then I would say that your statement is not correct. The service provider of those services decides how its webservices should be consumed and how it will respond.

Meaning if it expects the client/user to post its request, it could return an error if the user/client uses a get or vice versa.

Comment: OK, Thank you for correcting me. But then what is the difference between RESTful service and a simple service?

Comment: What is a "simple" service?

Comment: I mean to say web service which is not RESTful.

Comment: That question has been asked and answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636330/what-are-restful-web-services