# Does RESTFul mean URL shouldn't contain parameters

Tags: rest, web, restful-architecture

I've heard about the conception RESTFul for a long time but I always can't understand it clearly.

I've read the links below:
[What are RESTful web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636330/what-are-restful-web-services)
[What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

As my understanding, RESTFul means that the URL shouldn't contain any verb, meaning that an URL represents an unique resource. And also, the method GET shouldn't modify any resource and we should use POST to do so.

But I still have a question.
For example, if we want to search a user by his name, we can design the URL like this:

```
www.example.com/user?name=test
```

Or like this:

```
www.example.com/user/name/test
```

Can you tell me which one is RESTFul?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REST` resource is a noun, no notion of behavior should be in the uri, we use verbs to indicate action we are doing. Basically there are only two types of resources: Instance and Collections. So good practise is to use plurals in the uri: `users` instead of `user`:

`www.example.com/users GET` - fetch collection of all users

`www.example.com/users/1 GET` - fetch instance of a concrete user

`www.example.com/users POST` - create of a new user
etc.

`REST` is not a strict standard (but a list of [6 constraints](https://restfulapi.net/rest-architectural-constraints/)) says nothing about how search feature should be implemented. But definetely your first option `/users?name=test` seems preferable for me: tt is straightforward and this is a huge benefit.

As alternative you may want to investigate [OData protocol](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) - it is a standard to make queryable apis. `OData`-like solution would be:

```
/users?$filter=name eq 'test'
```

Also [Facebook APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/) is a good source for inspiration.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

When you are using rest - you are accessing resources through URI's and you can set actions on these resources through the HTTP request types.

There are different parameters that you can pass through REST request , there can be resource identifiers (That are usually passed through the URI - in your case the www.example.com/user/name/test is more restfull) or things like filters when you want to search, for example www.example.com/user/?age=....

In this post you can find more about best practices in passing parameters in rest:
[REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

REST, to start with, is not a protocol but just an architectural style that when followed correctly decouples clients from server APIs and thus make them tolerant to changes done on the serverside. It should therefore be regarded as a design approach for distributed systems.

The difference between a protocol and an architectural style is simply that the former one defines a rule set a server or client has to follow. It should be defined as precise as possible to reduce ambiguity and thus reduce the likelihood of incompatible implementations by different vendors. The latter one just contains suggestions how to design the overall application and/or message flow and outlining the benefits one gains by adhering to the design.

By that definition, REST is a generalization of the interaction style used for browsing Web content. A Web browser is able to make use of multiple protocols such as HTTP, FTP, SMTP, IMAP, ... and different flavors of it while remaining independant of any server specific implementation though being capable of interacting with it as the communication is done according to the rules of the protocol used. REST does follow this approach by building up on the same protocols (most often just HTTP) which an application implementing the RESTful architeturce approach should adhere to as well to stay compatible with other users of that protocol.

Similar to a Web browser, which does not care whether the URI string contains any semantical structure, REST doesn't care how the URI is designed or if the resource is named after a verb either. Both will use the URI just to invoke a resource on the server providing the resource. A RESTful client should thus not expect a certain URI to return a certain type (= [*typed* resources](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)). Though how will a client know what an invoked URI will return? The keywords here are *content-negotiation* and *media-types*.

The format exchanged by both, Web browser and REST, is negotiated between client and server. While for typical Web browsers the representation is probably one of the HTML variants (i.e. XHTML, HTML 5, ...) it is not limited to it. Your browser is probably capable of processing other media types as well, i.e. pictures, videos, PDF, ... As REST is just a generalization of this idea it also should not limit itself to just XML or JSON.

Media types are thus some kind of guildlines of how to process and interpret data received in a representation format outlined by the media type. It should define the syntax and semantics of a received payload i.e. like [`text/html`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2854), which defines that a received representation will have a case-insensitive `<html` token (`<xhtml` in case of XHTML) near the beginning of the content and that fragment identifiers (`#` character in URIs) are according to [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4.1) semantics and that certain tags like `A`, `IMG` or others may define a name attribute which act as a target for anchors. It may also define a more thorough description of the syntax and how to interpret it like in case of [`text/vcard` (vCard)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) (or one of its variants like  [`application/vcard+json` (jCard)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7095) or [`application/vcard+xml` (xCard)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6351)).

As media types are one of the most important parts of the RESTful design, most effort has to be put into its creation. A client that can't deduct the next possible actions from the media type needs some out-of-band information which often is hardcoded into the client and thus couples it tightly to the API itself. If the API will change in future, the chances that the client will stop working once the changes are applied on the server are fairly high (depending on the changes).

I hope I could shed some light on the idea behind REST and that the design of URI is not of relevance to a true RESTful client/API as the client might deduct what to do with that URI based on some relation name returned for the URI and the media-type which might state that a relation name such as `order` can be invoked to trigger a new order with the API rather than having the client to analyze something like `http://some.server.com/api/order/product/1234` or `http:/some.server.com/ajfajd/fj/afja`.

Further information and reasons why RESTful APIs should follow the design closely can be found in Roy Fielding famous blog post which [explains some of the constraints](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) an API should adhere to if it follows the RESTful approach.